# tsung ts_config_server Can't start newbeam on host (reason: timeout) Aborting

Tags: erlang, timeout, load-testing, tsung, beam

I am currently in the midst of doing distributed load testing on Amazon's EC2 services and have diligently followed all documentation/forum/support on how to get things to work, but unfortunately find myself stuck at this point. No one in any of the relevant IRC's has been able to answer this either...

Here is what I am seeing:

I am at a point where I can get Tsung to work perfectly well if I run it simply on the controller itself, but with options:

```
FROM tsung.xml
 <client host="tester0" weight="8" maxusers="10000" cpu="4"/>
```

Also - it works with higher/lower CPU values.

I can also very easily get it to work locally using:

```
use_controller_vm="true"
```

but this is of no use to me now, as I cannot get the throughput that I'd like.

In order to get things working, I have ssh keys installed.  I have opened all ports on these servers [ 0 - 65535 ] and have the exact same versions of Tsung, Erlang and, well, everything on the server is the same actually (they are images of each other).

Tsung version 1.4.2
Erlang R15B01
Ubuntu 12.04LTS
Same EC2 security group (all ports open - both TCP & UPD and NO iptables or SELinux)
Same EC2 availability zone

When I do start tsung, I get it to work when only send as above to tester0 and ts_config_server starts newbeam with:

```
ts_config_server:(6:<0.84.0>) starting newbeam on host tester0 with Args " -rsh ssh -detached -setcookie  tsung   -smp disable    +A 16 +P 250000  -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 64000  -kernel inet_dist_listen_max 65500  -boot /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung-1.4.2/priv/tsung -boot_var TSUNGPATH /usr/lib/erlang/ -pa /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung-1.4.2/ebin -pa /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung_controller-1.4.2/ebin +K true  -tsung debug_level 7 -tsung log_file ts_encoded_47home_47ubuntu_47_46tsung_47log_4720120719_451751"
```

However, whenever I try to run this with any remote server, the entire test fails and I get zero users:

```
<client host="tester1" weight="8" maxusers="10000" cpu="1"/>

ts_config_server:(6:<0.84.0>) starting newbeam on host tester1 with Args " -rsh ssh -detached -setcookie  tsung   -smp disable    +A 16 +P 250000  -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 64000  -kernel inet_dist_listen_max 65500  -boot /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung-1.4.2/priv/tsung -boot_var TSUNGPATH /usr/lib/erlang/ -pa /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung-1.4.2/ebin -pa /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung_controller-1.4.2/ebin +K true  -tsung debug_level 7 -tsung log_file ts_encoded_47home_47ubuntu_47_46tsung_47log_4720120719_451924"
```

However, when I try to run it with TWO clients (i.e, as below):

```
<client host="tester0" weight="8" maxusers="10000" cpu="1"/>
<client host="tester1" weight="8" maxusers="10000" cpu="1"/>
```

I once again get zero users to start hitting my web servers.  I'm not sure why and this is not intuitive to me at all.

```
ts_config_server:(6:<0.84.0>) starting newbeam on host tester1 with Args " -rsh ssh -detached -setcookie  tsung   -smp disable    +A 16 +P 250000  -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 64000  -kernel inet_dist_listen_max 65500  -boot /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung-1.4.2/priv/tsung -boot_var TSUNGPATH /usr/lib/erlang/ -pa /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung-1.4.2/ebin -pa /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung_controller-1.4.2/ebin +K true  -tsung debug_level 7 -tsung log_file ts_encoded_47home_47ubuntu_47_46tsung_47log_4720120719_451751"
ts_config_server:(6:<0.85.0>) starting newbeam on host tester0 with Args " -rsh ssh -detached -setcookie  tsung   -smp disable    +A 16 +P 250000  -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 64000  -kernel inet_dist_listen_max 65500  -boot /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung-1.4.2/priv/tsung -boot_var TSUNGPATH /usr/lib/erlang/ -pa /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung-1.4.2/ebin -pa /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung_controller-1.4.2/ebin +K true  -tsung debug_level 7 -tsung log_file ts_encoded_47home_47ubuntu_47_46tsung_47log_4720120719_451751"
```

One thing that I do notice is that, of all the args passed to slave:start, only ONE does not exist, and that is the one following the -boot directive:

```
/usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung-1.4.2/priv/tsung
```

Rather, in that directory, I have only the following files:

```
:~$ ls /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung-1.4.2/priv
tsung.boot                    tsung_controller.rel     tsung_recorder.boot         tsung_recorder.script
tsung_controller.boot         tsung_controller.script  tsung_recorder_load.boot    tsung.rel
tsung_controller_load.boot    tsung_load.boot          tsung_recorder_load.script  tsung.script
tsung_controller_load.script  tsung_load.script        tsung_recorder.rel
```

The last thing I've actually tried is to log what is happening with my ssh session when I try to slave:start, but I get no results.  I did this by running:

```
erl -rsh ssh -sname tsung -r ssh_log_me
```

Where ssh_log_me is:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "$0" "$@" > /tmp/my-ssh.log
ssh -v "$@"  2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/my-ssh.log
```

But I get no output when I run:

```
(tsung@tester0)1> slave:start_link(tester1, tsung, " -rsh ssh -detached -setcookie  tsung   -smp disable    +A 16 +P 250000  -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 64000  -kernel inet_dist_listen_max 65500  -boot /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung-1.4.2/priv/tsung -boot_var TSUNGPATH /usr/lib/erlang/ -pa /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung-1.4.2/ebin -pa /usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung_controller-1.4.2/ebin +K true  -tsung debug_level 7 -tsung log_file ts_encoded_47home_47ubuntu_47_46tsung_47log_4720120719_451751").
{error,timeout}
```

I have looked through erlang's -boot directive and through the actual erlang code (for ts_config_server) but I am a little lost at this point and might just be missing one last piece of information.

I ask that you please take a look at my xml file here:  http://pastebin.com/2MEbL6gd

Answer (score 0):

I recompiled using git's most current version and it worked --- odd that it didn't work with my installed deb package...

Goes to show you - compile from source when unsure!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure ssh key verification is disabled
~/.ssh/config Host * StrictHostKeyChecking no UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null

Make sure all ports are accessible across controller and worker nodes. If it is in the cloud make sure firewall or security groups allow all ports.
3.Erlang, Tsung must have same version.

4.Ensure all machines are reachable to each other

5.Run erlang test

erl -rsh ssh -name subbu -setcookie tsung Erlang R16B03-1 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.10.4 (abort with ^G) (daya@ip-10-0-100-224.ec2.internal)1> slave:start("worker1.com",bar,"-setcookie tsung").

Warning: Permanently added 'worker1,10.0.100.225' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts. {ok,bar@worker1}

Run this test from controller to all worker nodes.

You should be able run tests without any issues.

Good Luck!

Subbu